# Cohomology ring of grassmannian and Pieri rule

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, grassmannians, schubert-calculus

I am sorry if this question is not for mathoverflow. I asked the same question on stackexchange (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4203667/cohomology-ring-of-grassmannian-and-pieri-rule), but I didn't get an answer:

Let $X=OG(n,2n+1)$, where $OG(n,2n+1)$ denotes the variety of $n$-dimensional isotropic subspaces of a vector space $\mathbb{C}^{2n+1}$ with a nondegenerate symmetric bilinear form.

According to Theorem 2.2 a) (Page 17, Anders Skovsted Buch, Andrew Kresch, Harry Tamvakis, Quantum Pieri rules for isotropic grassmannians, https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.4966.pdf), the cohomology ring of X is given by
$$ H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}[\tau_{1},\ldots, \tau_{n}]/I,$$

where $I$ is the ideal generated by
$$ \tau_{r}^{2}-2\tau_{r+1}\tau_{r-1}+2\tau_{r+2}\tau_{r-2}+\cdots +(-1)^{r}\tau_{2r}$$
for $1\leq r\leq n$.

In particular, if $n=4$, then the ideal $I$ is generated by the following four elements

$$
\tau_{1}^{2}-\tau_{2},\quad \tau_{2}^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}+\tau_{4}, \quad \tau_{3}^{2}-2\tau_{4}\tau_{2},\quad \tau_{4}^{2}.\tag{*}\label{*}$$
But if I apply Pieri rule for X (Theorem 2.1, Page 16, Anders Skovsted Buch, Andrew Kresch, Harry Tamvakis, Quantum Pieri rules for isotropic grassmannians) to $\tau_{2}\cdot \tau_{2}$, I get the following relation

$$\tau_{2}^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}-\tau_{4} \tag{**}\label{**}$$

Therefore, combining (\ref{*}) and (\ref{**}), I get $2\tau_{4}=0$ in $H^{*}(X,\mathbb{Z})$. I seems that some computation is wrong, but I don't know where I made a mistake.

Thank you.

Comment: Asking a question on MO because it didn't get answered on math.SE is a great idea, but it's better to wait longer between asking on one site and another (to give people more of a chance to answer), and to put links from each question to the other (so people can avoid duplicating effort).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I added a link to math.SE.

Comment: The authors seem to assume $k>0$ at the beginning of section 2 (and so ruling out the Grassmanian $OG(n,2n+1)$), I'm not sure why though.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. But I guess that theorems hold for $k=0$ (maybe I'm wrong).

Comment: I know almost nothing about this topic, but it seems after a little reading it is common to treat the "maximal isotropic" case differently for some technical reason about partitions.  See page 3 of http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~coskun/poland-lec5.pdf.

Comment: It seems that the cohomology ring is correct according to page 9  of http://www.math.umd.edu/~harryt/papers/qcig.pdf

Comment: Are you sure that the element referred to as $\tau_4$ by one paper is not equal to the element referred to as $-\tau_4$ by the other?

Comment: I’m not completely sure that the sign changes but I hope so.

Answer (score 3):

The equation $\tau_2^{2}-2\tau_{3}\tau_{1}-\tau_{4}$ (obtained by Pieri rule) is incorrect. It should be
$$\tau_2^{2}-2\tau_{3,1}-\tau_{4},$$
so there is no problem for such computations.